# How to access docker's container file system

Tags: docker

I need to access the file system of a non-running docker's container. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Thanks,

Comment: do you need to alter it?

Comment: "non running docker image"... you mean "non running docker container" right?

Comment: @Thomasleveil - nope, only to examine it (and yes, I mean container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/export/) command is what you are after. It will print on the standard output the content of a container filesystem as a *tar* archive.

```
docker export <container_name> > my_container.tar
```

or

```
docker export --output="my_container.tar" <container_name>
```