# How to access react app which is ran in docker container?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    command: ["npm", "start"]
```

Commands which I fired to get this up

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build

After this I went to https://localhost:3000 and this project did not load.
Here is reproducible repo https://github.com/reyanshmishra/My-Portfolio-ReactJS

Thanks

Comment: How do you know the port is `3000`?

Comment: I have mentioned it in docker-compose.yml

Comment: No, I see you try using this port, but how do we know, you bind to this port your NodeJs application?

Comment: I am not getting you.

Comment: what I see is that you don't need ``run`` https://github.com/reyanshmishra/My-Portfolio-ReactJS/blob/master/Dockerfile#L10 did you tried with just ``CMD ["npm", "start"]`` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried CMD ["npm", "start"] as well with no luck.

Comment: What’s the output of docker-compose up?

Comment: its normal, just like local, there is not error.

Comment: If you’re on Windows your ports don’t get mapped to local host but to the VM running the docker daemon. Are you on windows?

Comment: Also the server can be listening on localhost only not on “all interfaces” 0.0.0.0 which also would prevent you connecting to it from your machine.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/147

Answer (score 0):

From [webpack-dev-server documentation](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) :

> Either method will start a server instance and begin listening for connections from localhost on port 8080.

I guess you can modifiy docker-compose.yml to :

```
ports:
      - "3000:8080"
```

And then you should be able to access your app using http://localhost:3000.

**OR**

You can modify your webpack config to use port 3000 instead of the default 8080 :

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    },
    port: 3000
},
```

Comment: You have correctly restarted the docker container ?

Comment: Tried both the option with no luck.

Comment: Yeah, I ran the build command again. Whats the best way to restart a container?

Comment: I don't know, the only thing i am sure is that your application is currently starting on port 8080 and not 3000. The line 3000:3000 is designed to map the port 3000 of your localhost to the port 3000 of your docker container. Since your application is currently starting on 8080, there is at least something wrong here.

Comment: There is something wrong thats the reason, I have posted asked, I am bagging my head since two days. Have tried almost everything on the internet.

Comment: What I meant by saying there is something wrong here, was not there is something wrong with your setup as I am pretty much aware of that. I meant there is something wrong with your port configuration. It might not have solved your overall problem but I am pretty confident on the fact that your port configuration is wrong, and that the solution I described is an improvement toward solving your overall issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the react project by building like this. You have to add this line into Dockerfile like this to run your application,

```
# Install `serve` to run the application.
RUN npm install -g serve
```

Example **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .

# Copy all local files into the image.
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix

# Build for production.
RUN npm run build --production

# Install `serve` to run the application.
RUN npm install -g serve

# Set the command to start the node server.
CMD serve -s build

# Tell Docker about the port we'll run on.
EXPOSE 5000
```

You can run image like this (your app will run **port 5000** by default. so you have to change **docker-compose.yml** file as well):

```
**$ docker run -p 5000:5000 <image name>**
```

- if you need to access the image without running the container,

  [How to access a docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858910/how-to-access-a-docker-image)
- if you need to access the running container

  **$ docker exec -ti  bash**

Comment: I want to set this up for dev environment, building for production and serving it has no issues.